# "error: implicitly declaring library function 'exit' with type" when configuring NetCDF on Mac

Tags: c, compilation, fortran, netcdf, fortran90

I need to compile the following project on a mac: [cost733clas-1.4_rev23.tgz](http://cost733.met.no/cost733clas-1.4_rev23.tgz) (download link)

The problem is, I have never worked with fortran or C and for the most part just worked with IDE's which took care of everything ...

Using the project [guide](http://cost733.met.no/cost733class_userguide.pdf) I found out, that I need a `fortran90` and a `C` compiler. Compilation using [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran) worked up to a point, but at some point it fails on a sub-package/dependency (netcdf).

```
...
checking nm flags... 
checking for C-equivalent to Fortran routine "SUB"... sub_
checking for Fortran "byte"... yes
checking for Fortran "integer*2"... yes
checking if Fortran "byte" is C "signed char"... configure: error: Could not compile conftest.c
configure: error: ./configure failed for netcdf-4.0.1
```

content of `config.log`:

```
configure:25351: gfortran -c -g -O2 conftest.f
configure:25354: $? = 0
configure:25356: result: yes
configure:25374: checking for Fortran "integer*2"
configure:25382: gfortran -c -g -O2 conftest.f
configure:25385: $? = 0
configure:25387: result: yes
configure:25414: checking if Fortran "byte" is C "signed char"
configure:25424: gcc -c  -g -O2 conftest.c
conftest.c:4:3: error: implicitly declaring library function 'exit' with type 'void (int) __attribute__((noreturn))' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                exit(values[1] != -2 || values[2] != -3);
                ^
conftest.c:4:3: note: include the header <stdlib.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'exit'
1 error generated.
configure:25427: $? = 1
configure:25468: error: Could not compile conftest.c
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what compiler I should try/what flags I should use? (and how to set them)

Comment: Fortran is incredibly backwards compatible, lack of support for the ancient Fortran90 standard is almost certainly not the issue.

Comment: As a first effort googling the line with the error message give a lot of hits - I would see if any of those are useful

Comment: What does `config.log` give as the reason for failing?

Comment: The error in config.log happens whem compiling C, not when compiling Fortran. The configure script's `-Werror` flag might not be ready for your GCC version.

Answer (score 0):

the solution to my problem was to use linux instead of mac, i'm not quite sure what went wrong on mac, but creating a virutal linux machine and doing the same there works just fine.

for people who want to create a virtual machine some useful links:

- https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/413594/what-does-no-bootable-medium-found-mean-in-virtualbox
- https://www.osboxes.org/ubuntu/#ubuntu-21-04-info
- https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-brew-ubuntu-20-04-lts-linux/